# How to simulate Amazon DynamoDB unique constraints using transactions and AppSync

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

This [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/) shows how to create unique attributes (email and name) in DynamoDB. I however am using AppSync (therefore GraphQL) to speak to DynamoDB and the post only gives a command-line examples / explanation. 
How do you add uniqueness to a DynamoDB table, using GraphQL and AppSync?

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm about to give up and write a lambda for this